# How to find the path of the "Shared Documents" folder from c#?

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-vista, directory

In Windows Vista, the special folder "Shared Documents" contains documents accessible by all the users in the machine. That folder was renamed to "Public Documents" in Windows 7.

How can I find its physical path from c#?

Note that `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.xxx)` doesn't have the folder I'm looking for.

Comment: Found this trick (it searches the registry): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/csharpgeneral/thread/86ce30d2-a679-4e6e-9ed2-42ad5ffe886c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PUBLIC"), "Documents");
```

Comment: This is a big fail and should not be marked as the answer. You should NOT hardcode names like "Documents".

Comment: @Anders "Documents" in this case is a system folder, what's a better alternative, other than using SpecialFolder CommonDocuments which isn't available until .NET 4.0?

Comment: @cxfx: PInvoke one of the SHGet*Folder api's like Ngu Soon Hui's answer

Answer (score 9):

The [`SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28VS.100%29.aspx) enum has had a large, and long overdue, update in .NET 4 - one of the new additions is the `CommonDocuments` member.

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder, IntPtr hToken,
   uint dwFlags, [Out] StringBuilder pszPath);

public string GetCommonDocumentsFolder()
{
    int SIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS = 0x002e;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero,SIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS,IntPtr.Zero,0x0000,sb);
    return SB.ToString();
}
```

Answer courtesy of, er..., [expert-exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/Q_22391652.html) that we all love to hate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
```

The file system directory that contains documents that are common to all users. This special folder is valid for Windows NT systems, Windows 95, and Windows 98 systems with Shfolder.dll installed.

Answer (score 0):

Look in ShlObj.h for more CSIDLs
interestingly enough SHGetFolderPath has been depricated...
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx